# H2 doesn't update row if there is no transaction

Tags: java, spring, testing, h2

I start `H2` in server mode and run very simple `Spock` test which:

1. Starts Spring application context
2. Updates field `A`
3. Checks field `A` value

I found that `H2` doesn't update field values if transaction is not opened. Is it correct behavior?

Comment: Yes... Would be strange to be able to persist something in a database without a transaction (or dangerous).

Comment: 1. Why should I open transaction for single update? 2. It differs from PostgreSQL / MySQL behavior - I can't be sure in my tests

Comment: Can you post the code which works on PostgreSQL or MySQL, and fails on H2?

Comment: MySQL can or cannot support transactions depending on the table type (MyISAM tables don't support transactions). Depending on your configuration you might have auto-commit on. Also you should always have transactions regardless of how many statements you execute, now it maybe one but it might end-up with multiple and you don't want mistakenly forget a transaction.